# What do I do with my answer if the questions gets closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

What should I do in case I wrote up an elaborated answer to a question and soon after the question gets closed for being a duplicate?

If I feel my answer has some value, what's the right thing to do? Should I post my answer to the original question then, even if it's long closed?

Or what do you suggest?

Comment: A request: *If* you decide to post it on the original, please 1) edit/comment on the answer to say you're doing so 2) delete the answer on the duplicate. It's easier to delete superfluous questions if it's obvious there are no useful answers attached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you believe your answer (or any other answer) is of enough value, flag the question to be merged. This will ensure that all relevant answers are on the same question, making it easier for people who come in via Google to find the best answer.

Comment: Thanks, ok that's what I will do from now on!